# Keycloak not sending email for events

Tags: jboss, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have configured Keycloak and have setup email as Event Listener. But Keycloak is not sending email notification for any of the Login Events. SMTP is properly configured and email has been setup in the Realm as well. Events are being logged (e.g LOGIN ERROR) and is visible on UI but email is not being sent for those events. Is there anything I am missing? Attaching Keycloak's event config setup. [image]

Comment: Is Keycloak able to sent email for Password change/New user creation etc?

Comment: Yes. I am getting emails for password reset/email verification.

Comment: is your email verified ?

Comment: Currently Keycloak only sends emails to the concerned user's account and for a very small set of login events. Cf. https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#event-types . So yes please indeed make sure the user under test has a valid email address and is verified if needed to). Even realm administrators do not receive mails about other users.