# How to make Keycloak 20.0.1 send an e-mail when a user is blocked due to too many failed login attempts?

Tags: keycloak

I want Keycloak to send an e-mail to a user whenever a user is blocked due to too many failed login attempts (see section `Realm Settings -> Security defenses -> Brute force detection`).

The event in question has the following properties:

- Error (`org.keycloak.events.Event#getError`) = `user_temporarily_disabled`
- Type (`org.keycloak.events.Event#getType`) = `LOGIN_ERROR`

**How can I do that**, i. e. make Keycloak send an e-mail to the user when such event occurs?

**Known ways to implement it**

One obvious way to do it is to write a class that implements the `org.keycloak.events.EventListenerProvider` interface, detect the event in its `onEvent` method and trigger sending of the e-mail at some custom server (i. e. send a request to that server and it will contact an SMTP server).

Second is a variation: Detect the event in the same method and somehow make Keycloak send the e-mail using Keycloak SMTP settings ("Realm settings -> Email -> Connection & Authentication").

The screenshot in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389055/keycloak-not-sending-email-for-events) made met think (possibly wrongly) that there may be a way to make Keycloak send emails upon the occurrence of certain events "out of the box," i. e. without writing custom event listeners.

**Update 1:** If someone else wants to do this, I recommend to look at [this answer](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/send-email-on-event/3062/5). The code below worked for me.

```
RealmModel realm = this.model.getRealm(event.getRealmId());
    UserModel user = this.session.users().getUserById(event.getUserId(), realm);
    if (user != null && user.getEmail() != null) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + user.getEmail());

        org.keycloak.email.DefaultEmailSenderProvider senderProvider = new org.keycloak.email.DefaultEmailSenderProvider(session);
        try {
            senderProvider.send(session.getContext().getRealm().getSmtpConfig(), user, "test", "body test",
                    "html test");
        } catch (EmailException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycloak does indeed support sending emails for events out of the box. However, it can only be configured by event (LOGIN_ERROR), and not by further filtered types (user_temporarily_disabled).

For this, you will need to implement your own EventListener, but it should be easy to heavily copy code from Keycloak's existing EmailEventListener, which you can find here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/events/email/EmailEventListenerProvider.java

In there, you'd change the implementation of L59 in `onEvent(Event event)` to check your two conditions (event type and error), rather than checking against some list of configured fixed events. Your event will be added to the currently running transaction, and when the transaction ends (in success or error), Keycloak will send an email via the SMTP settings that are configured in the realm.

If you want to customize the template and subject lines of the email, you'll have to provide your own freemarker templates in src/main/resources/theme-resources/templates/{html,text}. Both the html and text folder need to contain an .ftl file of the same name. Message keys for use in the template and the subject go in src/main/resources/messages/messages_{en,fr,de,...}.properties files.

With the template and messages configured, you can use one of the 2 `send(...)` methods available in the `EmailTemplateProvider` class

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom event listener with below code

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.keycloak.email.EmailException;
import org.keycloak.email.EmailTemplateProvider;
import org.keycloak.email.freemarker.FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider;
import org.keycloak.events.Event;
import org.keycloak.events.EventListenerProvider;
import org.keycloak.events.EventType;
import org.keycloak.events.admin.AdminEvent;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.models.RealmModel;
import org.keycloak.models.UserModel;
import org.keycloak.services.managers.BruteForceProtector;
import org.keycloak.theme.FreeMarkerUtil;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class CustomEventListener implements EventListenerProvider {
    
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CustomEventListener.class);

    
    private final KeycloakSession session;
    protected RealmModel realm;
    protected UserModel user;
    

    public CustomEventListener(KeycloakSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        try {
            if (event.getType() == EventType.LOGIN_ERROR) {
                realm = session.getContext().getRealm();
                user = session.users().getUserById(event.getUserId(), realm);
                boolean isTempDisabled = session.getProvider(BruteForceProtector.class).isTemporarilyDisabled(session, realm, user);
                System.out.println("EVENT:   tempDisabled=" + isTempDisabled + ", isEnabled=" + user.isEnabled() );
                if (isTempDisabled) {
                    sendLockoutEmail(realm, user);
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable eex) {
            log.errorf(eex, "Failed to send email on account lockout due to : ");
            eex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        
    public void sendLockoutEmail(RealmModel sessionRealm, UserModel sessionUser) {
        String realmName = sessionRealm.getName();
        List<Object> subjectParams = List.of(realmName);
        Map<String, Object> mailBodyAttributes = new HashMap<>();
        mailBodyAttributes.put("email", user.getEmail());
        try {
            EmailTemplateProvider emailProvider = session.getProvider(EmailTemplateProvider.class);
            emailProvider.setRealm(sessionRealm);
            emailProvider.setUser(sessionUser);
            emailProvider.send("Temporary user lockout", subjectParams, "locked-out-info.ftl", mailBodyAttributes);
        } catch (EmailException eex) {
            log.errorf(eex, "Failed to send access code email. realm=%s user=%s", sessionRealm.getId(), sessionUser.getUsername());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // Cleanup code goes here
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(AdminEvent event, boolean includeRepresentation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }   
}
```

Now Create a `locked-out-info.ftl` file in your email custom theme with the ftl code

```
<html>
<body>
${kcSanitize(msg("userLockedoutHtml", email, realmName))?no_esc}
</body>
</html>
```

also add `userLockedoutHtml=Whatever the message with email : {0}` in messages_en.properties file

Restart your keycloak, got to events section and add this new event listener in config event listeners